# Why use `deps` property in DI

Tags: angular, angular2-di

Here is the code snippet from [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html):

```
{ provide: RUNNERS_UP,    useFactory:  runnersUpFactory(2), deps: [Hero, HeroService] }

...

export function runnersUpFactory(take: number) {
  return (winner: Hero, heroService: HeroService): string => {
    /* ... */
  };
};
```

My question is why `deps` property is used here? What are the general cases for using `deps`?

Comment: See the manual https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/FactoryProvider-interface.html , it is quite exhaustive on this.

Comment: @estus, thanks, I've seen the manual. I usually ask a question to get a broader picture, while the manual just says that it's used with factory providers. But is it limited to it? Are there any other use cases? etc. These are the questions I have in my head

Comment: Yes, it is limited to factories. The benefit of TS is that properties don't come out of nowhere, they are defined with interfaces (FactoryProvider here).

Comment: @estus, got itl, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a way to tell Angular dependency injections what dependencies it needs to inject to the factory function returned by `runnersUpFactory`.

For services there is the `@Injectable()` class to tell DI that it needs to analyze the constructor parameter of this class (same for `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, and `@Pipe()`), but this seems not to work for functions. Therefore they introduced the `deps` parameter.

DI will look up a provider using the key `Hero` and another one using `HeroService` and then will pass them as parameters to the factory function in the same order.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/FactoryProvider-interface.html

> **`deps : any[]`**
>   A list of tokens which need to be resolved by the injector. The list of values is than used as arguments to the `useFactory` function.

Comment: thanks, so it's basically only relevant when `useFactory` is used, correct? when the other providers are used, like `useClass`, `useValue` and `useExisting`, it has no purpose?

Comment: Exactly - only for `useFactory`

Comment: Great, thanks. Just a quick follow-up, is there any other provider besides the ones I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: That's the kind of inconsistency I don't like on Angular 2

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8578682dcfccc2ccccb68df37c3ebc738f98bf0e/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.ts#L167-L175

Comment: @Karl A function cannot be annotated for DI with decorators, that's TS limitation. If you're after consistency, you can always annotate it like `factoryFn.parameters = [[new Inject(dep)]]` instead of `deps: [dep]`, that's common syntax for all DI.

Comment: @Estus, Gunther! Thanks to both for very useful insights ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [Are you sure they're only for `useFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259998/859154) ? I've asksed it yesterday and was told  - no.

Comment: @RoyiNamir seems reasonable. Might be handy in rare (I guess) situations. Haven't seen it before.

Comment: Its not documented well, but `deps` can be used with `useClass`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594944/can-deps-be-also-used-with-useclass/48597926#48597926

Comment: @pixelbits thanks for the info. Royi linked to your answer already. It makes sense, it just didn't occur to me it could be useful, but I can imagine scenarios.