# how the parameters of a forRoot() module's method is passed to a provider?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I found some examples of module's forRoot() method like the one below:

```
export class CoreModule {
constructor(
@Optional()
@SkipSelf()
parentModule: CoreModule
) {
if (parentModule) {
  throw new Error(
    'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only'
  );
 }
}
static forRoot(someParameters?:string[]): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
  ngModule: CoreModule,
  providers: [AnProvider1, AnProvider2]
 };
}
```

But how can I to pass the parameter values to any of the module's declared providers ?

Comment: what is _parameter values_? what exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `InjectionToken` to register the parameters with the injector. Then use DI passing in the `InjectionToken` with the `deps` property as follows:

```
export const Params= new InjectionToken<string[]>('params');

...

static forRoot(someParameters?:string[]): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
  ngModule: CoreModule,
  providers: [
            { provide: Params, useValue: someParameters },
            { provide: AnProvider1, useClass: AnProvider1, deps:[Params] },
            AnProvider2
  ]
};
```

In your component constructor, use the `InjectionToken`:

```
constructor(@Inject(Params) someParameters: string[])
```

Comment: Can deps be used with useClass ? I thought they are only for useFactory

Comment: Yes they can. It would be useful when you’re injecting generic dependencies that require explicitly named tokens