# Can `deps:[]` also be used with `useClass`?

Tags: javascript, angular

I already know what/how to use  `deps`.
It is when a factory method needs Injected tokens , so we need to supply them like :

```
const randomFactory = (car,engine) => { return ... };
 ...
 providers: [Car,Engine, 
             { provide: 'Random', 
               useFactory: randomFactory ,  
               deps: [Car, Engine],
             },
            ]
```

But I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821955/859154) :

> > so it's basically `deps` only relevant when `useFactory` is used, correct?
> >      ->Exactly - only for `useFactory`

But then I've asked [in other place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259998/859154)  :

> Can deps be used with useClass ? I thought they are only for useFactory –
>   -> Yes they can. It would be useful when you’re injecting generic dependencies that require explicitly named tokens

*I didn't want to continue comments in two places and hence my question :*

**Question:**

In which scenarios would I use `useClass` with `deps` ?

Also , even if I used it , say class `Foo` :

```
Class Foo
{
 constructor ( private s1:Service1 , private s2:service2){}
}
```

^ Which *already(!) have a ctor* of its own. Where would deps dependencies  be injected ? ( appended to ctor??)

}

An example of scenario + code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two kinds of providers:

**StaticProvider** and **Provider**

[image]

### StaticProvider

It's kind of providers that are used to configure Injector in a static way(**without Reflection**).

According to the [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d9d00bd)

> platformXXXX() no longer accepts providers which depend on reflection.
> Specifically the method signature went from Provider[] to
> StaticProvider[].

[Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

**What does it mean?**

1. When we pass provider to platform we have to specify `deps` because we have to use `StaticClassProvider` or `ConstructorProvider` instead of just `ClassProvider` (see picture above).

   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,
   {
   providers: [
   {
   provide: ElementSchemaRegistry,
   useClass: CustomDomElementSchemaRegistry,
   deps: [] <===================== required here
   }
   ]
   }
   );
2. When we create Injector dynamically we have to specify `deps` because `Injector.create` [takes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a86940ca553de512963524f2a86574fd0fe77ca/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L74-L90) `StaticProvider` array.

For instance:

```
export const MyParams = new InjectionToken<string[]>('params');

export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(MyParams) public someParameters: string[]) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.full;

  constructor() {
      const inj = Injector.create([
      { provide: MyService, useClass: MyService  } <=== we will get an error because we have to define deps
    ])
  }
}
```

https://ng-run.com/edit/5Xm4jwAoXXyAIspwF571

### Provider

It's kind of providers that we usually use when write providers in **@NgModule** or **@Component/@Directive** metadata

Looking at this answer: [how the parameters of a forRoot() module's method is passed to a provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259653/how-the-parameters-of-a-forroot-modules-method-is-passed-to-a-provider/48259998#48259998) I would say that `deps` is not required there. We only need to provide `Params` in providers array and angular will do all job for us.

---

@estus said that:

> deps are available only in useFactory providers but not in useClass
> providers.

because he meant `Provider`(more precisely `ClassProvider`) not `StaticProvider`.

---

**P.S.** You can also read my article about `StaticInjector` :)

- https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-how-staticinjector-replaces-reflectiveinjector-6f303d2798f6

Comment: If i understand correctly , i should see deps in the demo . But i didnt find it. (It shows an error) https://imgur.com/a/BG3Eg

Comment: You should add `, deps: [MyParams]` to do it working. I just showed that it's required in case of `Injector.create` here is the fixed version https://ng-run.com/edit/hqquxCxesyu4TQp9hwED

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `deps` may be used by `useFactory` or `useClass`.

You can see that this is true by looking at the Angular source (5+) for [packages\compiler\src\metadata_resolver.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L1045).  If `deps` is populated for either `useClass` or `useFactory`, then `deps` will be returned in the provider metadata:

```
getProviderMetadata(provider: cpl.ProviderMeta): cpl.CompileProviderMetadata {
    let compileDeps: cpl.CompileDiDependencyMetadata[] = undefined !;
    let compileTypeMetadata: cpl.CompileTypeMetadata = null !;
    let compileFactoryMetadata: cpl.CompileFactoryMetadata = null !;
    let token: cpl.CompileTokenMetadata = this._getTokenMetadata(provider.token);

    if (provider.useClass) {
      compileTypeMetadata = this._getInjectableMetadata(provider.useClass, provider.dependencies);
      compileDeps = compileTypeMetadata.diDeps; <-- ***HERE***
      if (provider.token === provider.useClass) {
        // use the compileTypeMetadata as it contains information about lifecycleHooks...
        token = {identifier: compileTypeMetadata};
      }
    } else if (provider.useFactory) {
      compileFactoryMetadata = this._getFactoryMetadata(provider.useFactory, provider.dependencies);
      compileDeps = compileFactoryMetadata.diDeps;  <-- ***HERE***
    }

    return {
      token: token,
      useClass: compileTypeMetadata,
      useValue: provider.useValue,
      useFactory: compileFactoryMetadata,
      useExisting: provider.useExisting ? this._getTokenMetadata(provider.useExisting) : undefined,
      deps: compileDeps, <-- ***HERE ***
      multi: provider.multi
    };
}
```

You can see from [packages\compiler\src\view_compiler\provider_compiler.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/provider_compiler.ts#L50) that `deps` is used to instantiate a multi provider:

```
if (provider.useClass) {
      const depExprs = convertDeps(providerIndex, provider.deps || provider.useClass.diDeps);
      expr = ctx.importExpr(provider.useClass.reference).instantiate(depExprs); <-- ***HERE***
} else if (provider.useFactory) {
      const depExprs = convertDeps(providerIndex, provider.deps || provider.useFactory.diDeps);
      expr = ctx.importExpr(provider.useFactory.reference).callFn(depExprs);<-- ***HERE***
}
```

The same is true for single providers (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/provider_compiler.ts#L89).

```
if (providerMeta.useClass) {
  providerExpr = ctx.importExpr(providerMeta.useClass.reference);
  flags |= NodeFlags.TypeClassProvider;
  deps = providerMeta.deps || providerMeta.useClass.diDeps; <-- ***HERE***
} else if (providerMeta.useFactory) {
  providerExpr = ctx.importExpr(providerMeta.useFactory.reference);
  flags |= NodeFlags.TypeFactoryProvider;
  deps = providerMeta.deps || providerMeta.useFactory.diDeps; <-- ***HERE***
}
```

So even though it is not well documented, `deps` can be used by `useClass` or `useFactory`.

As an aside, `deps` is ignored when using `useExisting` or `useValue` providers (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.x/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/provider_compiler.ts#L108):

```
} else if (providerMeta.useExisting) {
  providerExpr = o.NULL_EXPR;
  flags |= NodeFlags.TypeUseExistingProvider;
  deps = [{token: providerMeta.useExisting}];
} else {
  providerExpr = convertValueToOutputAst(ctx, providerMeta.useValue);
  flags |= NodeFlags.TypeValueProvider;
  deps = [];
}
```

That being said, in the typical case, having a `useClass` provider and explicitly naming dependencies in the `deps` array is usually not necessary.  You should let DI handle that for you implicitly.

I found some obscure use cases for it when trying to implement a static `forRoot` method as referenced by these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259653/how-the-parameters-of-a-forroot-modules-method-is-passed-to-a-provider/48259998#48259998) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686638/featuremodule-fails-during-an-aot-build-when-static-forroot-has-arguments).

Comment: Do you have ideas how this is supposed to work in practice? [It seems like it isn't](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVFqXblegWWDrIWOMGzE?p=preview). I didn't investigate that far to figure out why `deps` are in source code you've posted. But since ClassProvider interface doesn't have deps, this means that it's unsupported to some degree (to my knowledge, it never was).

Comment: It seems like support for `deps` was intentional (based on the source) and it does work if you choose to use them together.  As to whether it may be deprecated in the future, I cannot say... I agree that by not having `deps` in the class provider interface seems to suggest that it may not be the intended use case.

Comment: There is no technical reason why `deps` should not work for either as the implementation is very similar.  This may be a case where Angular has chosen to support `deps` for the `useClass` provider and give the developer flexibility to choose whether to use it or not.   Perhaps this inconsistency in the design of the framework should be addressed (anyone want to raise it to the core team?).

Comment: As I've figured out (I guess this is mentioned in another answer that mentions StaticInjector), `deps` can be used with classes only as [ConstructorProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/StaticProvider), i.e. it is workable with AOT but not JIT. That's likely the reason why it doesn't work in plunker.

Comment: Agreed - it is inconsitent. It works for AOT but ignored for JIT.

Answer (score 1):

`deps` are available only in [`useFactory` providers](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider) but not in [`useClass` providers](https://angular.io/api/core/ClassProvider).

That's because the method that was chosen by Angular team for DI annotation as preferable (emitted type metadata) is applicable only to class constructors. While regular functions that are used in `useFactory` providers can't make use of type metadata and need alternative annotation method, which is `dep` array.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501), classes can be alternatively annotated for DI with `parameters` static property. Both class provider `parameters` and factory provider `deps` accept an array consisting of provider tokens or arrays of decorator instances (like `[new Optional(), new Inject(...)]`).