# What is the difference in behavior between Provider and StaticProvider?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that returns `Provider[]`. I use it to apply some predefined providers to a component. While writing tests for that function, I realized that `Injector.create` will not accept `Provider[]`, but `StaticProvider[]`. Now, I see that difference in interface, but I don't understand difference in behavior. If I change my function to return `StaticProvider[]`(that requires change from `Type` to `ConstructorProvider`), nothing really change and all of my tests are passing. Same happens if I cast return value to `StaticProvider[]` for injector.

So I was wondering, what is actual change in behavior between the two, If it doesn't matter which one I use for my use case.

docs links:

https://angular.io/api/core/Provider

https://angular.io/api/core/StaticProvider

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594944/can-deps-also-be-used-with-useclass/48595518#48595518) answer

Comment: @Siddhant Hey, thanks for a link, it will be very helpful.